# Newline in Haskell String?

Tags: string, haskell, newline

How can I create a newline inside a String? Is it possible without using `IO ()`?

```
formatRow :: Car -> String
formatRow (a, d:ds, c, x:xs) = a ++ " | " ++ x ++ concat xs ++ " | " ++ show c ++ " | " ++ d ++ concat ds ++ (show '\n')
```

Comment: You could make your question clearer by 1) providing us with the definition of the `Car` type, and 2) giving an example of the desired result. We can assume from the way you use them that `xs` and `ds` are strings, and `a`, `d`, and `x` are Chars, but the whole example code is rather odd without further context.

Comment: Search `\n` in  [Real World Haskell - Chapter 7. I/O](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io.html) for reference.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

To create a string containing a newline, just write `"\n"`.

If you run your program on Windows, it will [automatically be converted](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.8.1/docs/html/libraries/base-4.13.0.0/System-IO.html#g:25) to `"\r\n"`.

Note that calling `show` on it will escape the newline (or any other meta-characters), so don't do `foo ++ (show "\n")` or `foo ++ (show '\n')` - just use `foo ++ "\n"`.

Also note that if you just evaluate a string expression in GHCi without using `putStr` or `putStrLn`, it will just call `show` on it, so for example the string `"foo\n"` will display as `"foo\n"` in GHCi, but that does not change the fact that it's a string containing a newline and it will print that way, once you output it using `putStr`.

Comment: So i should use putStrLn instead and this will display properly?

Comment: @Ash: Instead of what? If you want to print your rows one at a time, you can just use `putStrLn` instead of appending a newline to the string. If you want to concatenate the lines together before printing them, you still need to append the newline (using `"\n"`, not `show '\n')` and then print the resulting string using `putStr` or `putStrLn`.

Comment: thanks for `putStr`, useful for absolute noobs like me searching actually for 'why my newlines are not displayed in ghci as i wish them to'