# Haskell "\n" shown as string in IO String

Tags: string, haskell, io

```
imP:: Int -> IO String    
imP n = do
x <- getLine
if n >= 0 then return ( (concat (replicate n " ")) ++ fun1 x) else return ( fun2 n x)
where
    fun1 [] = ""
    fun1 (x:xs)
        | isAlpha x = [x] ++ fun1 xs
        | otherwise = "\n" ++ fun1 xs
    fun2 n [] = ""
    fun2 n (x:xs)
        | isAlpha x = [x] ++ fun2 n xs
        | otherwise = "\n" ++ (concat (replicate (abs n) " ")) ++ fun2 n xs
```

I have this code. And given an input "hello3mello" to getLine it returns:

```
"hello\nmello"
```

But I need:

```
"hello
 mello"
```

EDIT:

```
<interactive>:32:9:                                                                                                                                               
Couldn't match type `IO String' with `[Char]'                                                                                                                 
Expected type: String                                                                                                                                         
  Actual type: IO String                                                                                                                                      
In the first argument of `putStr', namely `(imP 3)'                                                                                                           
In the expression: putStr (imP 3)
```

Comment: How do you print it?

Comment: use "putStr" instead of "print" you will get right one

Comment: If you want to print out "hello
 mello" use :
putStr "\"hello\nmello\""

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944055/newline-in-haskell-string

Comment: I edited the first post. I get that error when using putStr or print or putStrLn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `putStr` is `String -> IO ()`, you can't apply it to `imP 3 :: IO String` because `putStr` expects a pure `String` not an `IO String`. Which is exactly what GHC's error message is reporting.

I assume you're not familiar with monads, so I'd recommend reading any of the many tutorials. In the meantime, use `\x -> imP x >>= putStr`