# New line in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, newline

I've been looking through previously asked questions and I can't find an answer that solves my problem, although I thought at least one of them would.  I'm simply trying to have a newline character added between my strings inside of a function.  Whenever I add a "\n" to a string, it simply prints the "\n"

```
import Data.List
-- aRow takes number of columns as argument
-- The idea is to use this function with the number of columns as argument.
-- Example, if we want 3 columns, we'd say aRow 3, and get "+---+---+---+"

aRow :: Int -> String
aRow n = "+" ++ take (4*n) (intercalate "" (repeat "---+")) ++ "\n|" ++ take (4*n) (intercalate "" (repeat "   |"))
```

This is the output I'm getting

```
"+---+---+---+---+\n|   |   |   |   |"
```

and I'd prefer

```
"+---+---+---+---+" 
"|   |   |   |   |"
```

Where the lines are on separate lines (Also there's supposed to be 3 spaces between the vertical bars, ignore my formatting.  I'm mainly trying to get the newline character working).  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5944062/1848654:

> If you just evaluate a string expression in ghci without using `putStr` or `putStrLn`, it will just call show on it, so for example the string `"foo\n"` will display as `"foo\n"` in ghci, but that does not change the fact that it's a string containing a newline and it will print that way, once you output it using `putStr`.

Long story short, you may want to use `putStr` as Haskell will default to using `show` on that string and that will display the `\n` plainly as it has done for you here.

Example:

```
import Data.List

main = putStrLn(aRow 4) 

aRow :: Int -> String
aRow n = "+" ++ take (4*n) (intercalate "" (repeat "---+")) ++ "\n|" ++      take (4*n) (intercalate "" (repeat "   |"))
```

Comment: Haha, I've actually tried that but being new to the language I couldn't quite get the type signature down.. could you help me out with that? Thanks.

Comment: @Cameron What type signature? `putStrLn (aRow 1)`

Comment: @Cameron I've included your code in my answer along with how you'd call that function using putStrLn appropriately, as melpomene suggested. Is it clear now?

Comment: And now I feel really stupid.  Functional programming is increasingly difficult to wrap my head around after spending countless hours on Python and C++.  Thank you @jakeehoffmann

Comment: No problem, chaining functions together to accomplish a task is the name of the game in functional programming. You generated this string using your function, then you want it to print nicely. You could add a third, intermediate function to the chain that adds "begin string" to the front and "end string" to the end. So on and so forth.